# Problem with Nestjs decorator when i try use function applyDecorators

Tags: nestjs, typescript-decorator

I try combine two decorators in one like in example on nestjs page.

```
export const ROLES_KEY = 'roles';
export const Roles = (...roles: string[]) =>  applyDecorators(
  SetMetadata(ROLES_KEY, roles),
  UseGuards(RolesGuard)
)
```

But I've got an error like this:

`@Roles('Admin') ^ TypeError: auth_nestjs_1.Roles is not a function`

Controller:

```
  @Roles('Admin')
  @Get('test')
  async test() {
    return this.storage.find();
  }
```

`Typescript: 4.3.5 "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.6"`

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: how you're importing `Roles`?

Comment: import { Roles } from '@framework/auth-nestjs';

Comment: @rudolf did you find any solutions?